# Why do I keep getting a 500 internal server error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-config

I built a Asp.net webpage and I have a site master file although when I run it I keep getting a 500 error. I know it has to do with my web.config file but I don't know what to put in it?

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I took away "", so now it says " Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive".

Comment: What is the error message, exactly?

Comment: Can we add this error message into the question, as in the screenshot? It appears to be hard to diagnose this without this critical piece of information and the link no longer shows the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the application pool under the .NET 2.0 framework in IIS, judging from the error message. Change it to run under .NET 4.0 and your error should be resolved.

Comment: I am hosting it on Godaddy and it already says that my ASP.NET version in 4.0

Comment: If you look at the error screen at the link in your original question, it clearly states `Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.6413; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.6414` GoDaddy may have the .NET 4.0 framework installed, but it isn't running your website in the 4.0 app pool.